# Is there a way to fake isTrusted=true events?

Tags: jquery

When using jquery, real user events typically have the isTrusted=true property. Is there a way to fake this propery and fire events by a script?

Comment: What exactly you have tried? Share your code in which you want to fake it.

Comment: I don't want to fake it, I want to protect my site from .net scripts.

Comment: No expert.. but if it's javascript, then it's client side, then it is untrusted by definition.  Never trust anything coming from the client!

Comment: A colleague told me .net applications with webbrowser elements might be able to fire trusted events. I tried, but I was not able to fake them - but I am no expert as well. So I thought I'd better ask

Comment: Any ideas on this yet, my workaround is using powershell and faking it...